# Select or new for a has_many input for Formtastic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, input, formtastic

I don't know if there is already an input to do this, another gem, I don't know, I haven't found anything, which is weird because it seems like a very required behaviour.

What I mean is some input that use a `<select name="user[person_id]">` and an `<input name="user[person_attributes][name]">` so it would create a new one or select from a list.

I wanted to know if there is anything that do this before I start to do the "bundled" input, instead of using 2 separated ones. And some Javascript to hide the text box if something was selected.

Answer (score 0):

You'll pretty much have to roll your own javascript for the dynamic bits. You can pass a collection in to the form input, that contains an special option such as:

`<%= input :person, :as => :select, :collection => Person.all.map {|p| [p.name, p.id]} + ["Create a new person", "new"] %>`

and then roll your own javascript to run via onChange, when the value is set to 'new', showing a form to create a new person.